# Is my MVC3 Password Handling Adequate

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, encryption, passwords

I have read a ton of articles about how to store and compare entered passwords, some old and some new, but all different.  Therefore, I took what I thought to be the best options and implemented the following.

Note that I created my own authentication provider and I am not using nor inheriting from the standard MS MembershipProvider (too bloated).  This is for a lighter volume site that does not need to be "uber-secure", but I would like to follow best practices.  I would just like some validation that I am not doing anything glaring wrong or opening up security holes.  Also, I looked at per-user password salting, but it seemed overly complex for my needs.  Is that a valid assumption?

First, I put the following **appSettings** key in my web.config, which is returned by my **configurationProvider** class.

```
<add key="PasswordEncryptionKey" value="qTnY9lf...40 more random characters here" />
```

Here is my code that publically **Authenticates** a user and privatly **Checks** the stored password against what what was entered as well as **Encodes** the password when saving.  I have not shown the add or update password methods as they use the same private methods.

```
public bool Authenticate(string emailAddress, string password, bool setAuthCookie = false)
{
  bool isAuthenticated = false;
  var member = _memberRepository.Find(m => m.Email == emailAddress).SingleOrDefault();
  if (member != null)
  {
    if (CheckPassword(password, member.Password))
    {
      isAuthenticated = true;
      FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(emailAddress, setAuthCookie);
    }
  }
  return isAuthenticated;
}

private bool CheckPassword(string providedPassword, string storedPassword)
{
  return EncodePassword(providedPassword) == storedPassword;
}

private string EncodePassword(string password)
{
  var hash = new HMACSHA1
               {
                 Key = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(_configurationProvider.PasswordEncryptionKey)
               };
  string encodedPassword = Convert.ToBase64String(hash.ComputeHash(Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(password)));
  return encodedPassword;
}
```

My only rules are:

- The password must be asynchronously encrypted in the database and can't be decrypted.
- The method should be reasonable safe against dictionary or other attacks (I'm not developing a FDIC insured site, just a basic intranet)

With this, is there anything glaring that I'm missing?

Comment: If you are writing an intranet site why not use windows security?

Your approach of rolling your on provider is a good one. the MS one is truly bloated.

Skimming over your code it's more or less what I do for public websites so I think you are doing fine with what you have written. Remember nothing is really secure once it's connected to a network you are just presenting layers of obstacles hoping an attacker with get bored and go away.

Comment: Sorry Peter... I should have clarified better.  It is an Internet based site, but for a charity group where <100 members will login.  I should have used the word "portal".  So it won't have a ton of traffic, but I'm developing it pro-bono to practice my skills, so I just want to know best practices.

Comment: Use PBKDF2 or bcrypt instead of rolling your own.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe your scheme is adequate, but it can be improved upon a little bit.

It seems to me that you have the beginnings of a salting scheme here, with your EncryptionKey that you have in your app.config file.  However, for best security practices, generally people use a different salt for each password, and store the salt alongside the hash in the database.

```
class MyAuthClass {
  private const int SaltSize = 40;
  private ThreadLocal<HashAlgorithm> Hasher;

  public MyAuthClass ()
  {
    // This is 'ThreadLocal' so your methods which use this are thread-safe.
    Hasher = new ThreadLocal<HashAlgorithm>( 
      () => new HMACSHA256(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(_configurationProvider.PasswordEncryptionKey)
    );
  } 

  public User CreateUser(string email, string password) {
    var rng = new RNGCryptoServiceProvider();
    var pwBytes = Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(password);
    var salt = new byte[SaltSize];
    rng.GetBytes(salt);

    var hasher = Hasher.Value;
    hasher.TransformBlock(salt, 0, SaltSize, salt, 0);
    hasher.TransformFinalBlock(pwBytes, 0, pwBytes.Length);
    var finalHash = hasher.Hash;
    return new User { UserName = email, PasswordHash = finalHash, Salt = salt };
  }
```

With a scheme such as this, your passwords are made more complex because if an attacker happened to get the hashes, he'd have to also guess the salt during a brute-force attack.

It's the same philosophy as your EncodingKey in your configuration file, but more secure since each hash has its own salt.  Checking entered passwords is similar:

```
  public bool IsPasswordCorrect(User u, string attempt) 
  {
    var hasher = Hasher.Value;
    var pwBytes = Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(attempt);
    hasher.TransformBlock(u.Salt, 0, u.Salt.Length, Salt, 0);
    hasher.TransformFinalBlock(pwBytes, 0, pwBytes.Length);
    // LINQ method that checks element equality.
    return hasher.Hash.SequenceEqual(u.PasswordHash);  
  }
} // end MyAuthClass
```

Of course, if you'd rather store the hashes as strings rather than byte arrays, you're welcome to do so.

Just my 2 cents!

Answer (score 1):

A few thoughts...

1. You should use HMACSHA256 or HMACSHA512 instead of HMACSHA1.  .NET4's default hashing algorithm is SHA256 now instead of SHA1.
2. When you get the bytes of your encryption key, you use the ASCII encoding, but you're computing the hash using the Unicode encoding.  Keep them consistent - use Unicode.
3. Consider salting your hash.
4. You say encryption, but you're really hashing.

Comment: Thanks David.  I will change my code based on points 1 and 2.  For point 3, is what I'm doing enough for a low volume site, or do today's standards truly require salting?  I know that's an ambiguous question, but would love your input.  For point 4, what's the difference?

Comment: Encryption means there's a key that allows you to encrypt and decrypt the value.  Hashing involves a one-way operation - there's really not a way to unhash a value (well, not an easy way as I understand it).  I'm not a security guru - these are things that I've had to deal with over the years.  Regarding salting, I've always considered it a good practice to observe.  I guess it really depends on how comfortable you are with the level of security and what type of data you're storing.  If it's PCI data, you may want to lock it down.  If it's pictures of your dog, well, I guess it depends.  :)

Comment: I'm glad I was able to help.  Good luck!